# How to display country name labels on an SVG map drawn with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am currently having trouble trying to display country names on a d3 world map.

Here is an image of a leaflet example which shows country names. This would be something I would like to add to my d3 version. JUST the country names if possible. If not I can always go the leaflet route but thought I'd try in d3 first.

[image]

Here is the d3 version

[image]

Here is how I am currently drawing the map

```
    // reference to actual element d3 selects
    this.svg = d3.select(this.mapContainer.nativeElement)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .call(zoom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'map');

    this.projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(225)
        .translate([this.width / 2, this.height / 1.5]);

    const path = d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection);

    let g = this.svg.append('g');

    // if unknown is not in the filter set remove it from the json
    const filteredWorldMapJson = this.worldMapJson.features;

    // features are a list of countries
    // ex: { type: 'Feature', properties: { name: 'United States }, geometry: { type: 'Polygon', coordinates[] }, id: 'USA' }
    let test = g.attr('class', 'countries')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(filteredWorldMapJson)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('class', d => d.id)
        .style('fill', d => this._mapService.getBinColor(d.id))
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('opacity', 0.8)
        .style('stroke-width', 0.3);

    // id = countries abbreviation
    this.svg.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(filteredWorldMapJson, (a, b) => a.id !== b.id))
        .attr('class', 'names')
        .attr('d', path);
```

The country names are part of the geojson so I assume I can grab that and append them to each country somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question - in general, you want to parse the label data (in this case country names) out of your geojson file and use the projected position of the the geographic feature the label belongs to to position the label on the map.

here's some code that does this:

```
// Filter down the labels by label rank (only show the most important labels)
var labelData = data.features.filter(function(d) {
  return d.properties.labelrank < 4;
});

var labels = grp.selectAll('text.label').data(labelData);

labels
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .classed('label', true);

labels
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return projection(d3.geo.centroid(d))[0];
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return projection(d3.geo.centroid(d))[1];
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', function(d, i) {
    // Randomly align the label
    var idx = Math.round(3 * Math.random());
    return ['start', 'middle', 'end'][idx];
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.properties.admin;
  });

labels.exit().remove();
```

full working example here http://blockbuilder.org/pnavarrc/75ec1502f51f86c2f43e

[image: world map with labels]

Comment: for a more complex example that solves the label overlap problem with zooming, check out http://blockbuilder.org/nitaku/ec5453f2e5c7f540b02ccd9cb085e40f

Comment: there is a whole search engine for d3js examples, called blockbuilder search.  here's a search for `world map labels` that I used to find these examples :-) http://blockbuilder.org/search#text%3Dworld%20map%20labels

Comment: is your example broken?